# limited Fibonacci sequence

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I want to implement a function that generates the Fibonacci sequence from `N` to `N+K` and returns `array[K]` items, with terms `(0<=N<=370; 0<=N+K<=371; 0<=K<=255)`.
the last try `n2` is out of need and out of term when inputs are `n:370, k:1`. How to progress this and skip last `n2` element without multiple `if` so I want to simplify my code. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

this is smart contract for blockchain where `int` is 256 bit and `n2` at last loop has overflow value when `N+K >= 369`.

```js
function getFibSeq(n, k) {
  let  numbers = [];

  let n1 = 0;
  let n2 = 1;
  let i = 0;
  let j = (n + k);

  while (i < j){
    if((i - n) >= 0){
      output.push(n1);
    }
    if((j - i - 1) > 0){
      let temp = n1;
      n1 = n2;
      if((j - i - 2) > 0) {
        n2 = temp + n2;
      }
    }

    i = i + 1;
  }

  return output;
}
```

Comment: What is `output`? Is that supposed to be `numbers`?

Comment: `if ((i - n) >= 0)` is usually written more clearly as `if (i >= n)`

Comment: What do you mean by "out of need and out of term"?

Comment: You can simply remove the last element of the array before returning;.

Comment: @Barmar is not possible, int overflow when `n:370`

Comment: You have types on your arguments, so I assume this is not JavaScript like your tags say. Also `int temp` is not JS either.